# How do I create links in Django such that other users can't access them?

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, django-models

I'm pretty confused about how do I prevent users' from accessing the data of other users.

The case at hand :

I'm creating a Notes + To-Do app in which a user logs in, creates their notes and tasks.

How to create links to those notes such that they aren't accessible by other users? As in the correct syntax for UserPassesTestMixin.

In the To-Do app, how do I keep the tasks of one user unique to them? Similarly for the note app, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "create links". For what you describe, the links don't change for people that have access or not. The difference if that a user that owns note 5 and goes to `/note/5/`, they should be able to see their note, but if another user goes to `/note/5/` they should either 1) get a 404 error (Note not found) or 403 (Permission Denied) just be redirected to another page (say, the home page), maybe with a message.

Using Class based views, this is easy to do.

### Prevent access to views

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class LoginRequiredAccessMixin(object):
   # This will ensure the user is authenticated and should
   # likely be used for other views

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(LoginRequiredAccessMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


 class AccessMixin(LoginRequiredAccessMixin):

   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      obj = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=self.kwargs['id'])

      # Assumes you have a notes.user, but change to created_by
      # or whatever is your user field name
      if obj.user == self.request.user:
          # User owns object
          return obj

      raise PermissionDenied("User has no access to this note")


class NoteView(AccessMixin, DetailView):
  # This is a regular DetilView, but with the Mixin,
  # you are overwriting the get_object() function.
  # If you don't want the Mixin, then you can just add
  # get get_object() function here. Except that with the
  # Mixin, you can reuse it for your UpdateView, DeleteView
  # and even across both your notes and task views
  model = Note
  template_name = 'note/details.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(NoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     # Add any special context for the template
     return context
```

If instead you want to just direct users to another page, you would do something like:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages

class NoteView(DetailView):
  model = Note
  template_name = 'note/details.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(NoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     # Add any special context for the template
     return context

  @method_decorator(login_required)
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     note = self.get_objet()
     if note and not note.user == self.request.user:
        messages.error(
            self.request,
            'You are not allowed to access this Note'
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    return super(NoteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You didn't supply any code so I cannot be more specific, but hopefully you get an idea of the two techniques. The first is usually a cleaner solution, and the Mixin I show can be shared across both your Note views and ToDo Tasks records, assuming they use the same user/created_by field name.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I think I've got it now :P. I used the UserPassesTestMixin for the 403 Forbidden error.

`class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`
The userpassestestmixin was used on the update, create and delete views.

Comment: That may replace the other method, but given that UserPassesTestMixin only takes the user as an argument, you still need to call get_object or something to get the object, so it is a much more common solution to overwrite that get_object function. But that's up to you.

Comment: yeah exactly I wrote a test function.
`def test_func(self):
        notes = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == notes.user:
            return True`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using functions (FBV) you could use `if request.user == item.user`

```
@login_required
def post_edit(request, post_id):
  item = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
  if request.user == item.user:
```

CBV - Class Based View - using UserPassesTestMixin

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
# [...]
```

Comment: this seems cool but what about the urls.py?
the urls.py would probably have something like `path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),`
and that would mean that anyone with that link could access it I suppose. But well I'll try. Thanks a lot for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator in Django called "user_passes_test"

You can import like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
```

For detail check docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)